# Dependency bean not injected when TestNG is used. If JUnit is used then the dependencies are injected correctly

Tags: spring-boot, selenium, testng

I am trying to automate a web application using Selenium, Spring Boot and TestNG.
When the test class is executed using TestNG then the required beans are not instantiated and autowired. However if I use JUnit instead of TestNG the beans are injected as expected. I observed that when TestNG is used the Spring Context is not created (The SPRING logo that gets displayed at the start is not appearing for TestNG)
Instead the star of log message looks like this ...

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.5.0
13:27:54.845 [main] DEBUG org.testng.TestNG - suiteXmlPath: "/tmp/testng-eclipse--2094791325/testng-customsuite.xml"


Test class that I am trying to execute ....   

    @SpringBootTest(classes = SeleniumTestNgApplication.class)
    class SeleniumTestNgApplicationTests {
    
    @Value("${application.url}")
    String appUrl;
    
    @Autowired
    LoginPage loginPage;
    
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(appUrl); 
        // at this point appUrl and loginPage is null when TestNG's @Test is used
        // if JUnit 4's @Test is used then appUrl and loginPage is instantiated
        // appUrl is key-value from application.yml, yet it is null when TestNG is used
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by extending my Test Class with AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests. Refer to the post [Integration testing a Spring Boot web app with TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537436/integration-testing-a-spring-boot-web-app-with-testng)